# How to make click and drag slider scrollable within device screen?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I was trying to create a click and drag slider like the one in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykcx3.png)

But the problem is that the scrollbar is going way beyond the elements but it should end at the last block.

Here's my result: https://i.imgur.com/YLnTvze.gifv

Here's my code:

```js
var slides = jQuery('#drag_slider_main .drag_slider_wrapper').children().length;
    var slideWidth = jQuery('#drag_slider_main').width();
    var min = 0;
    var max = -((slides - 1) * slideWidth);

    jQuery("#drag_slider_main .drag_slider_wrapper").width(slides*slideWidth).draggable({
        axis: 'x',
        drag: function (event, ui) {
            if (ui.position.left > min) ui.position.left = min;
            if (ui.position.left < max) ui.position.left = max;
        }
    });
```

```css
#drag_slider_main {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#drag_slider_main .drag_slider_wrapper {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.drag_slide {
    width: 240px;
    height: 600px;
    float: left;
}
p.drag_para {
    color: #000;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="drag_slider_main">
    <div class="drag_slider_wrapper">
     <div class="drag_slide odd_slider">
      <img src="https://downtondistillery.tk/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/Josh_Woodward_Gravity-1-mp3-image.jpg">
      <h3 class="drag_heading">LEMON</h3>
      <p class="drag_para">Being one of the most commonly used botanicals</p>
     </div>
     <div class="drag_slide even_slider">
      <img src="https://downtondistillery.tk/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/Josh_Woodward_Gravity-1-mp3-image.jpg">
      <h3 class="drag_heading">LEMON</h3>
      <p class="drag_para">Being one of the most commonly used botanicals</p>
     </div>
     <div class="drag_slide odd_slider">
      <img src="https://downtondistillery.tk/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/Josh_Woodward_Gravity-1-mp3-image.jpg">
      <h3 class="drag_heading">LEMON</h3>
      <p class="drag_para">Being one of the most commonly used botanicals</p>
     </div>
     <div class="drag_slide even_slider">
      <img src="https://downtondistillery.tk/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/Josh_Woodward_Gravity-1-mp3-image.jpg">
      <h3 class="drag_heading">LEMON</h3>
      <p class="drag_para">Being one of the most commonly used botanicals</p>
     </div>
     <div class="drag_slide odd_slider">
      <img src="https://downtondistillery.tk/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/Josh_Woodward_Gravity-1-mp3-image.jpg">
      <h3 class="drag_heading">LEMON</h3>
      <p class="drag_para">Being one of the most commonly used botanicals</p>
     </div>
     <div class="drag_slide even_slider">
      <img src="https://downtondistillery.tk/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/Josh_Woodward_Gravity-1-mp3-image.jpg">
      <h3 class="drag_heading">LEMON</h3>
      <p class="drag_para">Being one of the most commonly used botanicals</p>
     </div>
     <div class="drag_slide odd_slider">
      <img src="https://downtondistillery.tk/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/Josh_Woodward_Gravity-1-mp3-image.jpg">
      <h3 class="drag_heading">LEMON</h3>
      <p class="drag_para">Being one of the most commonly used botanicals</p>
     </div>
     <div class="drag_slide even_slider">
      <img src="https://downtondistillery.tk/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/Josh_Woodward_Gravity-1-mp3-image.jpg">
      <h3 class="drag_heading">LEMON</h3>
      <p class="drag_para">Being one of the most commonly used botanicals</p>
     </div>
    </div>
```

It's a wordpress site for which I am creating this slider that's why I have added `jQuery` in place $ and it is showing an error which I am unable to figure out.

I also tried setting the main div to `display: flex;` but it only gets all the child elements in one row which doesn't solve the purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've adjusted your code a bit, so it works (how I understood it should work, maybe I'm wrong)

JS:

```
var slides = jQuery('#drag_slider_main .drag_slider_wrapper').children().length;
var min = 0;
var max = (slides - 1) * 240;

jQuery("#drag_slider_main .drag_slider_wrapper").width(slides*240);

jQuery("#drag_slider_main .drag_slider_wrapper").draggable({
    axis: 'x',
    drag: function (event, ui) {
       var left = ui.position.left,
       offsetWidth = ($(this).width() - $(this).parent().width()) * -1;

       if (left > 0) {
         ui.position.left = 0;
       }
       if (offsetWidth > left) {
         ui.position.left = offsetWidth;
       }
    }
});
```

CSS:

```
#drag_slider_main {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#drag_slider_main .drag_slider_wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.drag_slide {
    width: 240px;
    height: 600px;
    float: left;
    overflow:hidden;
}
p.drag_para {
    color: #000;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

And you forgot to include jQuery-UI to your HTML file which is required for draggable:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="drag_slider_main">
    <div class="drag_slider_wrapper">
(...)
```

Comment: Can you tell me what is it that I was doing wrong? Also, could you help me out with the scrollbars? Really appreciate it.

Comment: Thank you @mirza I was able to do it myself but forgot to reply here. Thank you for the help.